# MASM "error A2206: missing operator in expression"

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Trying to get the base address with this code:

```
MOV EBX,FS:[0x30]
MOV EBX,[EBX + 0x0C]
MOV EBX,[EBX + 0x14]
MOV EBX,[EBX + 0x10]
```

Getting this error on every line: "error A2206: missing operator in expression"

What's the problem?

Comment: This is completely unsupported. Use `GetModuleHandle(0)` instead.

Comment: The `0x` prefix is a C-ism.

Comment: MASM [supports the 0x prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552157(v=vs.85).aspx), though I don't know in which version that was added. It could be worth trying the `h` suffix instead, in case the version that comes with MASM32 is too old.

Comment: @Michael: So it does - my bad. Learn something new every day.

Comment: You are using MASM32 which means you might be assembling using MASM 6.15 or a patched version of 6.14. That old version doesn't understand 0x prefix. So try things like `[EBX + 0Ch]` etc using the `h` suffix and a leading 0.

Comment: @Michael MASM doesn't support the 0x prefix. That link is to documentation for the Windows debugger, which uses a MASM-like syntax for expressions. MASM 14.0.23026.0 gives the same errors compiling the code as the original poster got.